# Override a keyvalue that is passed to a metaclass of a Baseclass by its childClass

Tags: python, inheritance, metaclass

When I derive the BaseClass by the ChildClass, the `BaseMetaClass.__new__(...)` is run twice. First with the keywordarg "foo" and second time with "bar".
Is it possible to override "foo" with "bar" before it is executed in the first place.
I don't care if it is run twice but in the first execution it should have the value of "bar".

```
class BaseMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something with attrs here
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class BaseClass(keywordarg="foo", metaclass=BaseMetaClass):
    pass

class ChildClass(BaseClass, keywordarg="bar"):
    pass
```

***Why am I trying this:***

I am trying this because I am figuring out how to override/ manipulate a decorator that registers a service.

***Things I have tried in addition***

I have already tried `__prepare__` which did not lead to a the outcome I was hoping for.

I also tried following which seems not to be a valid syntax

```
class ChildClass(BaseClass(keywordarg="bar)):
```

Comment: You didn't post your actual code so it's hard to say but usually this sort of thing is a design smell.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you provide, `BaseMetaclass.__new__` is executed exactly once for  `BaseClass` and then, exact once for `ChildClass`.

I can't imagine why you think it could be different. THe creation of `ChildClass` itself will only run the metaclass `__new__` code once, with the custom named arguments passed in that child class.

That is easy to visualize by simply adding a print call to to `__new__`:

```
class BaseMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something with attrs here
        print(name, kwargs)
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class BaseClass(keywordarg="foo", metaclass=BaseMetaClass):
    pass

class ChildClass(BaseClass, keywordarg="bar"):
    pass
```

And running this snippet outputs:

```
BaseClass {'keywordarg': 'foo'}
ChildClass {'keywordarg': 'bar'}
```

If you don't want "keywordarg" to be set when creating "BaseClass" at all, just don't pass it as a named argument. Otherwise, the code is working as expcted, and `BaseMetaClass.__new__` is executed a single time, with the argument `bar`, when the class is created.

Python can't "know beforehand" that ChildClass will inherit from BaseClass and change "keywordarg" when creating BaseClass - and even if it could be possible (it could by reading the source file itself and resolving references, essentially interpreting the Python code before it would be executed), what should it do if more than one class would derive from "BaseClass"? WHich of the children parameters it should pick?

You mention you are trying this in order to "register a service" - it looks like you have a "XY" problem: what you are trying to do is not how class creation, customized or not, work. Just spell what you are actually trying to achieve there, not this one step you thought you might need.

Comment: I was trying to create a BaseController in Flask which when inherited should have provided an override for the app.route() decorator. E.g. LoginController would have provided all routes under "URL/login/**".  "/login" would have been the kwarg. Because I only wanted to register the routes under this specific path, I was forced to register them during the creation of the BaseClass. I already managed to find a simpler solution to achieve this through inheritance. So potentially a design flaw. But still thanks.